# Call Uinavigationcontroller of a project in the other project not in appdelegate

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

Hello i have this code

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[RootViewController2 alloc] init]];
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = COLOR(2, 100, 162);  
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window layoutSubviews];
```

that work on

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
```

but when i add this in other class for call it , it show but after crash for object-send problem!! please how call it?